# Best method for determining tolerances based on production data

Tags: statistics

Say I am producing a wound coil which is ultimately going to be used in a colpitt's oscillator circuit. I measure the Ls and Rs of the coil, and then install it in a ferrite and then test it in the circuit, where I determine if it works or not, based on the resulting frequency and amplitude of the oscillator output.
What is the right statistics tool to help set the production tolerances for said coils? I was thinking that I can use the measures Ls and Rs and use them as the features, and the circuit performance to label the data good or bad, and use LDA to see if the good vs, bad coils are separable, and then set the tolerance based on the projected good coil's distribution mean and SD ...is this a good approach? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you're not satisfied with Millikan's answer, you might have better luck with this over at Stats.SE or Physics.SE

https://stats.stackexchange.com
https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the application, you can model the circuit and find what $L/R$ combinations will work, then accept the coil based on that.  You might make an allowance for measurement error and errors in the rest of the circuit.

If you are manufacturing the coil and don't know the application you need to trade off yield and the higher price a low yield will force with tighter specifications making the part more attractive to users.  You probably need to meet the competitor's specifications to have people interested in the part, then work to make the yield as high as possible.  If there are not direct competitors out there, you can look at the limits that will let you accept $90\%$ or $99\%$, then think about whether that will be acceptable to users.